# Magento 2: Interceptor Error better way to solve?

Tags: magento2, error, performance

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0 on WAMP.

When we receive below kind of error

> a:4:{i:0;s:414:"Recoverable Error: Argument 6 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface, none
>   given, called in
>   /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php

Will do follow steps

- Remove module folder from `var/generation`
- Run `magento setup:upgrade`, `magento setup:di:compile`, `magento cache:flush` Commands

At the time of `magento setup:di:compile`

Application Code Generator takes so much time.

In overall process takes approximately 10 minutes to solve above error. Is there any better way to solve it & saving time?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh  Let me check & gives u update

Comment: How about your current issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience:

We should work on `developer` mode when developing. This is because auto-generated classes (Proxy, Factory, Interceptor) will be generated on the fly. DI compile doesn't need in this mode, so we don't need to run it again and again.

And then, we need to delete `var/generation` and clear cache.